# Spring data unusual query

Tags: java, spring-data

i have a problem with spring data queries. I want to receive Users (List) where user has given role ( role is in a list ) and assignedOrders of this user (list) is empty or this orders are in given state (State is enum class).

I came up with such query:

```
List<User> findAllByRoleContainsAndOrdersAssignedStateIsNullOrOrdersAssignedStateEquals(State state,Role role);
```

but it do not work at all. It is complicated and i've never created such query before. Can you help me with that? Thanks a lot !

EDIT:
Piece of code :

```
@Entity
public class User implements Persistable {
...........
@Column(name = "ROLES")
@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
@ElementCollection(targetClass = Role.class)
private List<Role> role;
..........
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "driver")
private List<Order> ordersAssigned = new ArrayList<>();

}
@Entity
public class Order implements Persistable {
...........
@JoinColumn(name = "DRIVER_ID")
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY,cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
private User driver;

@Column(name = "STATE")
@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
private State state;
.............

}
```

Comment: I think it's better to use `@Query`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
@Entity
public class User {

    private String name;

    @ElementCollection
    @Column(name = "role")
    private List<Role> roles = new ArrayList<>();

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "user")
    private List<Order> orders = new ArrayList<>();

    public User(String name, Role... roles) {
        this.name = name;
        this.roles.addAll(asList(roles));
    }

    public enum Role {
        ROLE1, ROLE2
    }
}

@Entity
public class Order {

    private String title;

    @ManyToOne
    private User user;

    private State state;

    public enum State {
        STATE1, STATE2
    }
}

public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Long> {

    @Query("select distinct u from User u join u.orders o join u.roles r where r = ?1 and (o.state is null or o.state = ?2)")
    List<User> getUsers(User.Role role, Order.State state);
}
```

Working [example](https://github.com/Cepr0/restdemo/tree/master/src/main/java/restsdemo/example6).

More info is [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.query-methods) and [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.query-methods.at-query).

Comment: There are user contains list of orders where orders contains single state. And i need users where user role ( one from List of Roles) is equal to Role.DRIVER and assignedOrders (List<Order>) is empty or that orders has State.FINISHED.

Comment: @Unlucky please add to your question your model and interface (signature) of the method you need.

Comment: sorry, it was not complete. It is now.

Comment: @Unlucky see updated answer with `private List<Role> roles`.